# How do I do this using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, hierarchy

```
ID  kidID   grandKidID
1   3           7
1   3           8
1   4           9
2   5           10
2   6           11
```

There are two people 1 and 2 (under the ID column).
Mr 1 has two kids 3 and 4. (KidID column). They themselves have their own kids (grandKidID column)

Lets say we are only considering these three generations of people. People born in the 40s as the ID, people born in the 70s as the Kids and people born post 2000 as grand kids.

For a List such as above in memory, I want to write a LINQ query that gives me a list of IDs, with all their kids and the kids would have their own kids.

How can I do this in LINQ? The queries I write seem too tedious.

Comment: This is a table that is pulled into memory using nhibernate.

Comment: LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities? LINQ to Objects?

Comment: LINQ to SQL. But that doesn't matter. The object is in memory as a List.

Comment: Its a pretty big table. I condensed the example to display the principle :(

Comment: You're using linq2sql and you've tagged this question as nhibernate??? WHY?

Comment: This is bad data, which is why you're having a problem with it.  Based on what we have here, the only interpretation is that person `1` is both their own kid and their own grandkid.  If the intent is that the kids are separate and the grandkids are separate people in the same table, use different numbers to represent different people.  If the intent is that they're stored in their own tables, why would you store grandkids separately from kids?

Comment: @Bobson [I don't see how the person being his own grandkid could be a problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlJH81dSiw)

Comment: @developer747 - Thanks for clearing up the data.  I'd suggest considering whether you should get rid of the grandkid column, though.  What happens if you have another line where Person 4 has Person 7 as a kid, instead of Person 3?  That would mean inconsistent, which could cause other problems.

Comment: @bobson: Added some text to address your concern.

Comment: @developer747 - Still not how I'd do it, but a reasonable reason for doing it that way.  Sometimes denormalized data just fits better.  Be wary of what happens if you ever need to add a fourth generation, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
var results = people
    .SelectMany(p => p.Kids
        .SelectMany(c => c.Kids
            .Select(g => new { 
                ID = p.ID, 
                KidID = c.ID, 
                GrandKidID = g.ID
             })));
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by ID, and KidID

```
var result = data.GroupBy (x => new { ID = x.ID, KidID = x.KidID }).Select( x=> x.Key).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by ID, and extract the KidID, GrandKidID into a new Person. Repeat the process for the Kids.

```
class Person {
  public int ID {get; set; }
  public List<Person> Kids {get; set; }
}

List<Person> = snafuPersons
     .GroupBy(person => person.ID)
     .Select(group => new Person {
        ID = group.Key,
        Kids = group.GroupBy(kid => kid.KidID)
                .Select(kidGroup => new Person{
                   ID = kidGroup.Key,
                   Kids = kidGroup.Select(grandKid => 
                                     new Person { ID = grandKid.GrandKidID})
                                  .ToList()
                }).ToList()
      }).ToList;
```